# In Powershell, what is $input for?

Tags: powershell

I was trying to create a hash table,

```
$input = @{'G'=100;'E'=50;'D'=35;'A'=100}
```

and could not figure out for the life of me why it wouldn't display as usual with commands like `write-host`, or simply `$input`.  `write-host` returned `System.Collections.ArrayList+ArrayListEnumeratorSimple`. `$input` returned nothing.  No error was thrown.

On a hunch I renamed the hash table, and boom, it appears as normal.  Opening a new powershell tab in ISE, I observe that the variable `$input` is filled in with intellisense even though I have not defined it in this environment.

Now I'm curious: what is this system variable $input for?  I'm on version 4.

Comment: while I agree that this is a duplicate, given that it has the same answer as the linked question, the title of this question is very explicit and could act as an effective signpost for answer-seekers with a similar issue.  Is this taken into account when making question closure decisions?

Comment: Exactly. This answer is currently the top Google search result for "powershell $input" when you find out that the most stupidly named automatic variable has wasted half an hour of your life.

Comment: I answered, and then closed the question as duplicate (in that order, since I didn't find the dup first). One of the functions of duplicate questions on SO is to act as the very signpost mentioned, and in that way, it's perfectly fine that both the duplicate and this one exist, that they may bring in different people with different queries, and that one points to the other. Being closed as duplicate is not any kind of indictment on the asker or the quality of the question. Closed and deleted are separate for this reason and I haven't and won't nominate it for deletion. Hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[It's an automatic variable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables):

> ### `$INPUT`
>
> Contains an enumerator that enumerates all input that is passed
>   to a function. The `$input` variable is available only to functions and
>   script blocks (which are unnamed functions). In the Process block of a
>   function, the `$input` variable enumerates the object that is currently
>   in the pipeline. When the Process block completes, there are no
>   objects left in the pipeline, so the `$input` variable enumerates an
>   empty collection. If the function does not have a Process block, then
>   in the End block, the `$input` variable enumerates the collection of all
>   input to the function.

This is also available in PowerShell:

```
Get-Help about_Automatic_Variables
```

[I also have an open feature request for `Set-StrictMode` to handle detection of this](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3061).

Comment: Where did you find that?  Was that a simple google?  I didn't find it on initial search.  If you can link that'd be helpful.

Comment: @Mr.Budris it's already a link, click the first sentence. You can also run `Get-Help about_Automatic_Variables` in PowerShell.

Comment: great, the Get-Help about_Automatic_Variables is really what I was looking for.

Comment: @Mr.Budris also, `Get-help about_Automatic_Variables -Online` will open the link for you :)

Comment: @Mr.Budris and see the link in my latest edit; I opened a feature request to make this easier to detect when using strict mode.

Comment: How does PS know the process block is finished? The provider may pipe a slow stream... is it waiting for EOF?

Comment: @Marc the wording is a little bit confusing on that part maybe. "The process block" there really means "all process blocks have finished executing" which means there are no more items. It's a bit of a circular reference, but think of it this way: _each_ process block executes once for _each_ item in the pipeline, 1 by 1. When there are no more items, then the process blocks don't execute anymore. The `End` blocks begin executing and at that point the `$input` variable will be an empty collection.

Comment: I'm piping a `Get-Content myfilebeingedited.txt -watch` into powershell scriptlets and they happily wait once the end of file is reached i.e. no more items are in the pipe and the process block stays "open". As I add new content to the file and save - it arrives in the `process{}` block of the receiving scriptlet and `end{}` is only executed when I Ctrl+C to end the program.

Comment: @Marc you might want to open a new question if you want a detailed answer, but that sounds expected to me. `-Watch` is blocking on new content being added to the file. When it finds some it sends it out the pipeline like it would with any other file content. From there the pipeline is working as expected; the commands down the line have no idea where the data is coming from (what the previous command is) they just receive an item and process it.