# How to MOCK a PowerShell cmdlet that appears multiple times with different purposes in a function using Pester?

Tags: powershell, pester

I would like to know if it is possible to Mock the same cmdlet in a function that return different object data types?

Below shows the function that has `Get-ADGroupMember` cmdlet appearing 2 times. I would like both `Get-ADGroupMember` to return different objects & data types using `Mock` cmdlet.

I am expecting to have the first `Get-ADGroupMember` to return a `System.Array` object type & the second `Get-ADGroupMember` to return a `PSCustomObject` type.

Thanks in advance for helping.

I have tried to Mock the cmdlet using what I have researched from the web & Pester documentation but has found no success.

```
BeforeAll {
    function Get-Something 
    {
        ## Initialize an array for PSCustomObject
        $ArrayCustomObject = @()
        
        ## Return an Array Object
        $ArrayObject = (Get-ADGroupMember "AD_Group_Name").SamAccountName
    
        foreach ($Object in $ArrayObject)
        {
            ## Return a PSCustomObject + SamAccountName is not the same as the previous SamAccountName
            $PSCustomObject = Get-ADGroupMember $ADMember | Select-Object objectClass, SamAccountName 
    
            $ArrayCustomObject += $PSCustomObject
        }
    
        return $ArrayCustomObject
    }
}

Describe "Get-Something" {
    Context "MOCK Get-ADGroupMember" {
        BeforeAll {
            ## Would like to have the first cmdlet to be mock with this
            Mock -CommandName Get-ADGroupMember -MockWith {
                [PSCustomObject]@{SamAccountName = "AD_GROUP_1"},
                [PSCustomObject]@{SamAccountName = "AD_GROUP_2"}
            }
            ## Would like to have the second cmdlet to be mock with this
            Mock -CommandName Get-ADGroupMember -MockWith {
                [PSCustomObject]@{objectClass = "User"; SamAccountName = "USER_1"},
                [PSCustomObject]@{objectClass = "User"; SamAccountName = "USER_2"}
            }
        }

        It "Get-ADGroupMember should run 2 times" {
            Get-Something -ADGroupName "ANY_AD_NAME"
            Assert-MockCalled Get-ADGroupMember -Times 2
        }

        It "Should Match PSCustomObject" {
            (Get-Something -ADGroupName "ANY_AD_NAME").count | should -be 2
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the result:

```
Describing Get-Something
 Context MOCK Get-ADGroupMember
   [+] Get-ADGroupMember should run 2 times 25ms (22ms|3ms)
   [-] Should Match PSCustomObject 13ms (12ms|0ms)
    Expected 2, but got 4.
Tests completed in 137ms
Tests Passed: 1, Failed: 1, Skipped: 0 NotRun: 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `-ParameterFilter` on a `Mock` to scope it to a specific use of a cmdlet based on the parameters used with it. In your example we can make a Mock match just the first use of `Get-ADGroupMember` by having a parameter filter that checks `$Identity` is set to "AD_Group_Name". The other `Mock` we then don't use a Parameter Filter on and it will get used for the other usage.

The following works (note I had to declare `Get-ADGroupMember` as a function in my example because I don't have that Module installed on my system at the moment):

```
BeforeAll {

    function Get-ADGroupMember {
        param($Identity)
    }

    function Get-Something {
        ## Initialize an array for PSCustomObject
        $ArrayCustomObject = @()
        
        ## Return an Array Object
        $ArrayObject = (Get-ADGroupMember "AD_Group_Name").SamAccountName
    
        foreach ($Object in $ArrayObject) {
            ## Return a PSCustomObject + SamAccountName is not the same as the previous SamAccountName
            $PSCustomObject = Get-ADGroupMember $ADMember | Select-Object objectClass, SamAccountName 
    
            $ArrayCustomObject += $PSCustomObject
        }
    
        return $ArrayCustomObject
    }
}

Describe "Get-Something" {
    Context "MOCK Get-ADGroupMember" {
        BeforeAll {
            Mock -CommandName Get-ADGroupMember -ParameterFilter { $Identity -eq 'AD_Group_Name' } -MockWith {
                [PSCustomObject]@{SamAccountName = "AD_GROUP_1" },
                [PSCustomObject]@{SamAccountName = "AD_GROUP_2" }
             
            } 
            Mock -CommandName Get-ADGroupMember -MockWith {
                [PSCustomObject]@{objectClass = "User"; SamAccountName = "USER_1" },
                [PSCustomObject]@{objectClass = "User"; SamAccountName = "USER_2" }     
            }
        }

        It "Get-ADGroupMember should run 3 times" {
            Get-Something -ADGroupName "ANY_AD_NAME"
            Assert-MockCalled Get-ADGroupMember -Times 3
        }

        It "Should Match PSCustomObject" {
            $Result = (Get-Something -ADGroupName "ANY_AD_NAME")
            
            $Result.count | should -be 4
            $Result.objectClass | Should -Contain 'User'
        }
    }
}
```

Also I changed the checks of your test. We expect `Get-ADGroupMember` to run 3 times, once outside the loop (where it returns 2 results) then twice in the loop (once for each result). And we expect the `Count` returned to be 4, because each time its called in the loop it returns 2 results, so 4 total. I added a further check to make sure we're getting the `objectClass` property at the end to prove the right Mock was being called.

Comment: I do have another question, so I want "AD_Group_Name" string to be replaced by a param from `Get-Something` function. For example, `Get-Something` function now has a `param($input)` and I am replacing `Get-ADGroupMember "AD_Group_Name"` to `Get-ADGroupMember $input`. In this case, how should I modify the `ParameterFilter` to condition to any value given to `$input` param.

Comment: In your Pester script you have control over what inputs you give to the functions when you execute them for testing, so you just need to make the parameter filter match that input. FYI if you're genuinely using `$input` as your parameter name I would recommend changing it, as $Input is an automatic variable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43241124/in-powershell-what-is-input-for

Comment: I finally figured out the issue on mocking `Get-AdGroupMember` cmdlet within `Get-Something` function with a param. For some reasons, `-eq` operator is not working as expected when using the cmdlet but it work when using your custom function. To get the expected behavior from the cmdlet, I have to use `-match` operator on the `$Identity` parameter. Here's the link to the full code if you wanna to test it out yourself with `Get-AdGroupMember` cmdlet. https://gist.github.com/JKChai/36ef5bef32576e34ce432e7293fddddd

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the automatic variable and thank you for point it out. 